# Hangman game in c++

Tags: c++

So i decided to make a hangman game today..i sat down and started writing, but i feel like i'm doing things the long way. I'm still learning c++ so i don't know if theres an easier way, but heres how i'm doing it right now..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
string word = "undefined";
char guess;
int incorrect = 0;
bool a = false;
bool b  = false;
bool c = false;
bool d  = false;
bool e  = false;
bool f  = false;
bool g  = false;
bool h  = false;
bool i  = false;
bool j  = false;
bool k  = false;
bool l  = false;
bool m  = false;
bool n  = false;
bool o  = false;
bool p  = false;
bool q  = false;
bool r  = false;
bool s  = false;
bool t  = false;
bool u  = false;
bool v  = false;
bool w  = false;
bool x  = false;
bool y  = false;
bool z  = false;
bool ga = false;
bool gb  = false;
bool gc = false;
bool gd  = false;
bool ge  = false;
bool gf  = false;
bool gg  = false;
bool gh  = false;
bool gi  = false;
bool gj  = false;
bool gk  = false;
bool gl  = false;
bool gm  = false;
bool gn  = false;
bool go  = false;
bool gp  = false;
bool gq  = false;
bool gr  = false;
bool gs  = false;
bool gt  = false;
bool gu  = false;
bool gv  = false;
bool gw  = false;
bool gx  = false;
bool gy  = false;
bool gz  = false;
int checkletterdog();
int checkWin();



void guessletter();

int main()
{
    cout << "welcome to josh's hangman game!" << endl;
    cout << "Generating random word....\n\n" << endl;
    srand(time(NULL));
    //int wordpicker = (rand()%10) + 1;
    int wordpicker = 1;
    switch(wordpicker) {
case 1:
    word = "dog";
    cout << "---\n";
    d = true;
    o = true;
    g = true;
    guessletter();
    checkletterdog();
    guessletter();
checkletterdog();
guessletter();
checkletterdog();
checkWin();
guessletter();
checkletterdog();
checkWin();
guessletter;
checkletterdog();
checkWin();
    break;








    return 0;

}

void guessletter(){
    cout << "Incorrect guesses: " << incorrect << endl;
    cout << "Guess a letter" << endl;
    cin >> guess;
}

int checkletterdog(){
    if(gd == true && incorrect<5){
        switch(guess){
        case 'o':
            cout << "Correct!\ndo-" << endl;
            go = true;
            break;
        case 'g':
            gg = true;
            cout << "Correct!\nd-g" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "INCORRECT" << endl;
            incorrect++;
        }
    }else if(go == true && incorrect<5){
        switch(guess){
        case 'd':
            cout << "Correct!\ndo-" << endl;
            gd = true;
            break;
        case 'g':
            gg = true;
            cout << "Correct!\n-og" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "INCORRECT" << endl;
            incorrect++;
        }
    }else if(gg == true && incorrect<5){
        switch(guess){
        case 'd':
            cout << "Correct!\nd-g" << endl;
            gd = true;
            break;
        case 'o':
            go = true;
            cout << "Correct!\n-og" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "INCORRECT" << endl;
            incorrect++;
        }
    }else if(gd == true && go == true && incorrect<5){
        switch(guess){
        case 'g':
            cout << "Correct!\ndog" << endl;
            gg = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "INCORRECT" << endl;
            incorrect++;
        }
    }else if(gd == true && gg == true && incorrect<5){
        switch(guess){
        case 'o':
            go = true;
            cout << "Correct!\ndog" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "INCORRECT" << endl;
            incorrect++;
        }
    }else if(go == true && gg == true && incorrect<5){
        switch(guess){
        case 'd':
            cout << "Correct!\ndog" << endl;
            gd = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "INCORRECT" << endl;
            incorrect++;
        }

    }else if(incorrect >= 5){
        cout << "You lose...better luck next time" << endl;
    }else{
        switch(guess){
        case 'd':
            cout << "Correct!\nd--" << endl;
            gd = true;
            break;
        case 'o':
            cout << "Correct!\n-o-" << endl;
            go = true;
            break;
        case 'g':
            gg = true;
            cout << "Correct!\n--g" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "INCORRECT" << endl;
            incorrect++;
    }
    }

}

int checkWin(){
        if(gd == true && go == true && gg == true && incorrect<5){
        cout << "YOU WIN!!" << endl;
        return 0;
}
}
```

i have a list of words but i only started on the first one so that's all i included. Is there a shorter way of doing this..?
EDIT: I changed it to a loop, that lets the player guess, checks the letter, and checks if the game is over

```
case 1:
    word = "dog";
    cout << "---\n";
    d = true;
    o = true;
    g = true;
    while(over != true){
    guessletter();
    checkletterdog();
    checkEnd();
    }
    break;

int checkEnd(){
        if(gd == true && go == true && gg == true && incorrect<5){
        cout << "YOU WIN!!" << endl;
        over = true;
} else if(incorrect == 5){
    cout << "You lose!\nBetter luck next time..." << endl;
    over = true;
}
}
```

those are the parts of code that i changed.. but is there an easier way where i wouldnt have to re-do everything manually for the other words?

Comment: Are you... hard-coding the solution to "dog"?

Comment: First, learn how to use arrays (or anything like it. vector...)

Comment: Try using a loop instead of manually calling `guessletter()` and `checkletterdog()` repeatedly.  It's not only more flexible, but it's less error prone. And in fact that block in your code contains an error: the line `guessletter;` is missing a ()

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something about those long list of bools.  Stick them in an array (as deviantfan pointed out) or something.

```
bool isLetterInWord[26] =  {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z};

// Initialize letters to false
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
  isLetterInWord[i] = false;

//Accessing dog as in your example
isLetterInWord[3] = true;
isLetterInWord[14] = true;
isLetterInWord[6] = true;
```

That's still a really inefficient way to do things, but still an improvement over the original code.

Other tips:

Try to avoid using `using namespace std`.  Brings all that unnecessary code to this short, little hangman program.  Use inline namespacing (i.e. `std::cout`) or using std::Insert std object you're using here.

Answer (score 0):

@Josh hey I have tried to create an example Hangman class and implement the Hangman game.

Have a look at this: [Demo Link](http://ideone.com/NEHpaM)

The `main()` method would look like this:

```
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Hangman h("jack sparrow");

    while ( !h.isLost())
    {
        char guess;
        std::cout << "Guess Letter: ";
        std::cin >> guess;
        bool res = h.play(guess);

        h.print();

        if (h.isWin())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (h.isLost())
    {
        std::cout << "You have lost" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fundamentally wrong.

You are basically hard-coding the behaviour of the program for the word "dog".  Assuming you get it to work, what would you end up with? A program that must be deeply rewritten whenever you want to play with another word. It's completely wrong. I understand you are a beginner, and beginners might choose an approach that is not optimal, and it can even be a good thing because by making mistakes you can learn a lot; but in this case it is so bad I feel you have to abandon it immediately. The concept is that **you can't write code that is tailored on specific data. You want to write code that works on generic data, so that when you need to change your data, you change just that and it immediately works.** Your `checkletterdog()` function is really wrong. The fact itself that the name of the function contains a reference to the data it's dealing with ("dog") is normally an indicator that your design is wrong. Do you see how much code you have written just to deal with a 3-letter word? Do you realise that a longer word would take MUCH more code? And that you'd have to add a lot of code for every new word? This is not sustainable.

Try to work on this: your `checkletter()` function must consider all the letters of the words, one by one. This must be automatic, that is, if the word is "dog" it will automatically check "d", "o", "g"; if it is another word, like "tiger", it will check "t", "i", "g", "e", "r". Nowhere in your code you will see anything like (pseudocode here!)

```
if (word == "dog") {
    check('d') and in case print it, else print '-'
    check('o') and in case print it, else print '-'
    check('g') and in case print it, else print '-'
} else if (word == "tiger") {
    //do the same stuff with the letters of tiger
}
```

On the contrary, you must write some code that can go through the letters of a string, whichever string it is. Then, for each of these letters, check if it has been guessed by the player. If yes, print it (whichever it is); if no, print `'-'`.

A practical suggestion: one way would be to define a vector of letters, and initialise this vector to the full alphabet. These are the options a player has. Every time a player chooses one, you have to remove it from that vector (assuming the choice was correct, that is, the player chose a letter that hadn't been chosen yet, which might not be the case, but for now we can assume the player doesn't give wrong commands) and check whether the word contains that letter. If so, add the letter into another vector (initially empty) of correctly guessed letters; otherwise, add it into a vector of wrong guesses (though this might not be fully required). Then, show the updated status: go through each letter of the word, and if you find it it the vector of correctly guessed letters, print it, otherwise print `'-'`.

This way you can deal with any word, without ever needing to rewrite code.

If all of this seems too hard, I'd say you should focus on other exercises for the time being. You'll get there eventually, but maybe you need to study some more now.